# How to create a function that returns the result of applying a function to a value in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm brand new to Prolog, and its way of creating functions is warping my head a bit.

In Python, I would do

```
def get_result(func, inpt):
    return func(inpt)
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing in Prolog. I've found from the tutorial that in Prolog, when writing functions you usually put the return value as the last argument. Then you get the result of a function by doing `function(..., X)` and then it will spit out `X = ...` as your answer.

So, I tried to do this:

```
get_result(Action, State, Result) :- Action(State, Result).
```

but Prolog is giving me the error `Syntax error: operator_expected`.

How do I write a function that will give me the result of the first argument applied to the second in Prolog?

Comment: Prolog doesn't have *functions*. It has *predicates*. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **call** : 
For example :

```
double(X,Y) :-
    Y is 2 * X.

get_result(Action, State, Result) :- call(Action, State, Result).
```

With result :

```
?- get_result(double, 3, R).
R = 6.
```